# Why does clickevent in minecraft not work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a tellraw command in Minecraft and all of the text appears but upon clicking the text I want all players to die. But instead of all players dying nothing happens. Here is my command:

```
tellraw @a {"text":"Kill all people?""color":"green","clickEvent":{CommandValue":"/kill @a"}}`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two things missing or wrong.

- `"text":"Kill all people?""color":"green"` is invalid JSON - it's missing a comma
- `clickEvent` uses the action `run_command` to execute commands

Taking both into account this will work assuming you're using the latest version of Minecraft:

`/tellraw @a {"text":"Kill all people?","color":"green","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/kill @a"}}`

Comment: I don't think the slash before "kill" is necessary.

Comment: @Fabian maybe not, but it works with it and I'm used to it :)

Comment: Thanks, my brother was just teaching me and he forgot how to do some of the stuff. I tried run_command but i didn't have that comma.